# How to set median value in edit mode trough script?

Tags: python, scripting, edit-mode

Its possible to change that's median (global) value trough script?

[image]

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Are you looking to transform the selected faces, so that their median global location will be some other xyz vector value?

Comment: yes that's right, i get confused due there are no tooltips if hover on their median value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**BMesh version.**

For an edit mode script can also use an edit mode bmesh.

Test script, move selected verts such that their mean global location is (1, 0, 0)

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

coord = Vector((1, 0, 0))
space = 'GLOBAL'

context = bpy.context


ob = context.edit_object
mw = ob.matrix_world
coord = coord if space == 'LOCAL' else mw.inverted() @ coord
me = ob.data

bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
# need at least one selected
o = sum((v.co for v in verts), Vector()) / len(verts)

bmesh.ops.translate(
        bm,
        verts=verts,
        vec= coord - o
        )
        
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should calculate the midpoint manually, then the difference vector that moves vertices and finally move selected parts in local coordinates because blender stores vertex-locations in local coordinates.

this code does such work: (just enter your desired value into `world_pos` variable)

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector as vec, Matrix as mat

# this is your input world position for center
world_pos = vec((4,0,0))

def move_center(world_pos:vec):
    obj = bpy.context.object
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    selected_verts = [v for v in obj.data.vertices if v.select]
    print(selected_verts)
    if len(selected_verts) == 0:
        return
    center_local = vec((0,0,0))
    for v in selected_verts:
        center_local += v.co
    center_local /= len(selected_verts)
    local_pos = obj.matrix_world.inverted() @ world_pos
    dif = local_pos - center_local
    for v in selected_verts:
        v.co += dif
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    move_center(world_pos)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i just run that's script in edit mode with selected face but get error, https://prnt.sc/1jcnv03
it seem the script doesn't work on mine
could you please clarify or edit your answer?

Comment: @cheatPKL check this one out

Comment: thank you, now its work as i wanted